# How to reparse video with stable "overall bit rate" ? (FFmpeg)

Tags: c, video, ffmpeg

I have such code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

extern "C"
{
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavfilter/buffersink.h>
#include <libavfilter/buffersrc.h>
#include <libavutil/opt.h>
#include <libavutil/pixdesc.h>
}

static AVFormatContext *ifmt_ctx;
static AVFormatContext *ofmt_ctx;

typedef struct StreamContext {
    AVCodecContext *dec_ctx;
    AVCodecContext *enc_ctx;
} StreamContext;
static StreamContext *stream_ctx;

static int open_input_file(const char *filename)
{
    int ret;
    unsigned int i;

    ifmt_ctx = NULL;
    if ((ret = avformat_open_input(&ifmt_ctx, filename, NULL, NULL)) < 0) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot open input file\n");
        return ret;
    }

    if ((ret = avformat_find_stream_info(ifmt_ctx, NULL)) < 0) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot find stream information\n");
        return ret;
    }

    stream_ctx = (StreamContext *) av_mallocz_array(ifmt_ctx->nb_streams, sizeof(*stream_ctx));
    if (!stream_ctx)
        return AVERROR(ENOMEM);

    for (i = 0; i < ifmt_ctx->nb_streams; i++) {
        AVStream *stream = ifmt_ctx->streams[i];
        AVCodec *dec = avcodec_find_decoder(stream->codecpar->codec_id);
        AVCodecContext *codec_ctx;
        if (!dec) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Failed to find decoder for stream #%u\n", i);
            return AVERROR_DECODER_NOT_FOUND;
        }
        codec_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(dec);
        if (!codec_ctx) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Failed to allocate the decoder context for stream #%u\n", i);
            return AVERROR(ENOMEM);
        }
        ret = avcodec_parameters_to_context(codec_ctx, stream->codecpar);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Failed to copy decoder parameters to input decoder context "
                "for stream #%u\n", i);
            return ret;
        }
        /* Reencode video & audio and remux subtitles etc. */
        if (codec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO
            || codec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
            if (codec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
                codec_ctx->framerate = av_guess_frame_rate(ifmt_ctx, stream, NULL);
            /* Open decoder */
            ret = avcodec_open2(codec_ctx, dec, NULL);
            if (ret < 0) {
                av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Failed to open decoder for stream #%u\n", i);
                return ret;
            }
        }
        stream_ctx[i].dec_ctx = codec_ctx;
    }

    av_dump_format(ifmt_ctx, 0, filename, 0);
    return 0;
}

static int open_output_file(const char *filename)
{
    AVStream *out_stream;
    AVStream *in_stream;
    AVCodecContext *dec_ctx, *enc_ctx;
    AVCodec *encoder;
    int ret;
    unsigned int i;

    ofmt_ctx = NULL;
    avformat_alloc_output_context2(&ofmt_ctx, NULL, NULL, filename);
    if (!ofmt_ctx) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Could not create output context\n");
        return AVERROR_UNKNOWN;
    }


    for (i = 0; i < ifmt_ctx->nb_streams; i++) {
        out_stream = avformat_new_stream(ofmt_ctx, NULL);
        if (!out_stream) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Failed allocating output stream\n");
            return AVERROR_UNKNOWN;
        }

        in_stream = ifmt_ctx->streams[i];
        dec_ctx = stream_ctx[i].dec_ctx;

        //ofmt_ctx->bit_rate = ifmt_ctx->bit_rate;
        ofmt_ctx->duration = ifmt_ctx->duration;

        if (dec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO
            || dec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
            /* in this example, we choose transcoding to same codec */
            encoder = avcodec_find_encoder(dec_ctx->codec_id);
            if (!encoder) {
                av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_FATAL, "Necessary encoder not found\n");
                return AVERROR_INVALIDDATA;
            }
            enc_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(encoder);
            if (!enc_ctx) {
                av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_FATAL, "Failed to allocate the encoder context\n");
                return AVERROR(ENOMEM);
            }

            /* In this example, we transcode to same properties (picture size,
            * sample rate etc.). These properties can be changed for output
            * streams easily using filters */
            if (dec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
                enc_ctx->gop_size = dec_ctx->gop_size;
                enc_ctx->bit_rate = dec_ctx->bit_rate;
                enc_ctx->height = dec_ctx->height;
                enc_ctx->width = dec_ctx->width;
                enc_ctx->sample_aspect_ratio = dec_ctx->sample_aspect_ratio;
                /* take first format from list of supported formats */
                if (encoder->pix_fmts)
                    enc_ctx->pix_fmt = encoder->pix_fmts[0];
                else
                    enc_ctx->pix_fmt = dec_ctx->pix_fmt;
                /* video time_base can be set to whatever is handy and supported by encoder */
                enc_ctx->time_base = av_inv_q(dec_ctx->framerate);
                enc_ctx->framerate = av_guess_frame_rate(ifmt_ctx, in_stream, NULL);
            }
            else {
                enc_ctx->gop_size = dec_ctx->gop_size;
                enc_ctx->bit_rate = dec_ctx->bit_rate;
                enc_ctx->sample_rate = dec_ctx->sample_rate;
                enc_ctx->channel_layout = dec_ctx->channel_layout;
                enc_ctx->channels = av_get_channel_layout_nb_channels(enc_ctx->channel_layout);
                /* take first format from list of supported formats */
                enc_ctx->sample_fmt = encoder->sample_fmts[0];
                //enc_ctx->time_base = (AVRational){ 1, enc_ctx->sample_rate };
                enc_ctx->time_base.num = 1;
                enc_ctx->time_base.den = enc_ctx->sample_rate;

                enc_ctx->framerate = av_guess_frame_rate(ifmt_ctx, in_stream, NULL);
            }

            /* Third parameter can be used to pass settings to encoder */
            ret = avcodec_open2(enc_ctx, encoder, NULL);
            if (ret < 0) {
                av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot open video encoder for stream #%u\n", i);
                return ret;
            }
            ret = avcodec_parameters_from_context(out_stream->codecpar, enc_ctx);
            if (ret < 0) {
                av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Failed to copy encoder parameters to output stream #%u\n", i);
                return ret;
            }
            if (ofmt_ctx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER)
                enc_ctx->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;

            out_stream->time_base = enc_ctx->time_base;
            stream_ctx[i].enc_ctx = enc_ctx;
        }
        else if (dec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_UNKNOWN) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_FATAL, "Elementary stream #%d is of unknown type, cannot proceed\n", i);
            return AVERROR_INVALIDDATA;
        }
        else {
            /* if this stream must be remuxed */
            ret = avcodec_parameters_copy(out_stream->codecpar, in_stream->codecpar);
            if (ret < 0) {
                av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Copying parameters for stream #%u failed\n", i);
                return ret;
            }
            out_stream->time_base = in_stream->time_base;
        }

    }
    av_dump_format(ofmt_ctx, 0, filename, 1);

    if (!(ofmt_ctx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
        ret = avio_open(&ofmt_ctx->pb, filename, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Could not open output file '%s'", filename);
            return ret;
        }
    }

    /* init muxer, write output file header */
    ret = avformat_write_header(ofmt_ctx, NULL);
    if (ret < 0) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Error occurred when opening output file\n");
        return ret;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int ret;
    AVPacket packet = {0};
    packet.data = NULL;
    packet.size = 0 ;
    AVFrame *frame = NULL;
    enum AVMediaType type;
    unsigned int stream_index;
    unsigned int i;
    int got_frame;
    int(*dec_func)(AVCodecContext *, AVFrame *, int *, const AVPacket *);

    if (argc != 3) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Usage: %s <input file> <output file>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    av_register_all();
    avfilter_register_all();

    if ((ret = open_input_file(argv[1])) < 0)
        goto end;
    if ((ret = open_output_file(argv[2])) < 0)
        goto end;

    /* read all packets */
    while (1) {
        if ((ret = av_read_frame(ifmt_ctx, &packet)) < 0)
            break;
        stream_index = packet.stream_index;
        type = ifmt_ctx->streams[packet.stream_index]->codecpar->codec_type;
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_DEBUG, "Demuxer gave frame of stream_index %u\n", stream_index);

        /* remux this frame without reencoding */
        av_packet_rescale_ts(&packet,
            ifmt_ctx->streams[stream_index]->time_base,
            ofmt_ctx->streams[stream_index]->time_base);

        ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(ofmt_ctx, &packet);
        if (ret < 0)
            goto end;

        av_packet_unref(&packet);
    }

    av_write_trailer(ofmt_ctx);
end:
    av_packet_unref(&packet);
    av_frame_free(&frame);
    for (i = 0; i < ifmt_ctx->nb_streams; i++) {
        avcodec_free_context(&stream_ctx[i].dec_ctx);
        if (ofmt_ctx && ofmt_ctx->nb_streams > i && ofmt_ctx->streams[i] && stream_ctx[i].enc_ctx)
            avcodec_free_context(&stream_ctx[i].enc_ctx);
    }
    av_free(stream_ctx);
    avformat_close_input(&ifmt_ctx);
    if (ofmt_ctx && !(ofmt_ctx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE))
        avio_closep(&ofmt_ctx->pb);
    avformat_free_context(ofmt_ctx);

    return ret ? 1 : 0;
}
```

This is a little bit changed code from official example of using ffmpeg called [transcoding.c](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.2/transcoding_8c-example.html)

I only read packets from one stream and write them to another stream. It works fine.

Proof below.
[image]

then I add to main a condition. If it is a packet with video frame, I will decode it, then encode and write to another stream. **No other actions with frame.**

My addition code below:

```
static int encode_write_frame(AVFrame *filt_frame, unsigned int stream_index, int *got_frame) {
    int ret;
    int got_frame_local;
    AVPacket enc_pkt;
    int(*enc_func)(AVCodecContext *, AVPacket *, const AVFrame *, int *) = avcodec_encode_video2 ;

    if (!got_frame)
        got_frame = &got_frame_local;

    av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_INFO, "Encoding frame\n");
    /* encode filtered frame */
    enc_pkt.data = NULL;
    enc_pkt.size = 0;
    av_init_packet(&enc_pkt);
    ret = enc_func(stream_ctx[stream_index].enc_ctx, &enc_pkt,
        filt_frame, got_frame);
    if (ret < 0)
        return ret;
    if (!(*got_frame))
        return 0;

    /* prepare packet for muxing */
    enc_pkt.stream_index = stream_index;
    av_packet_rescale_ts(&enc_pkt,
        stream_ctx[stream_index].enc_ctx->time_base,
        ofmt_ctx->streams[stream_index]->time_base);

    av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_DEBUG, "Muxing frame\n");
    /* mux encoded frame */
    ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(ofmt_ctx, &enc_pkt);
    return ret;
}

static int filter_encode_write_frame(AVFrame *frame, unsigned int stream_index)
{
    int ret;
    av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_INFO, "Pushing decoded frame to filters\n");

    while (1) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_INFO, "Pulling filtered frame from filters\n");

        ret = encode_write_frame(frame, stream_index, NULL);
        if (ret < 0)
            break;
        break;
    }

    return ret;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int ret;
    AVPacket packet = {0};
    packet.data = NULL;
    packet.size = 0 ;
    AVFrame *frame = NULL;
    enum AVMediaType type;
    unsigned int stream_index;
    unsigned int i;
    int got_frame;
    int(*dec_func)(AVCodecContext *, AVFrame *, int *, const AVPacket *);

    if (argc != 3) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Usage: %s <input file> <output file>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    av_register_all();
    avfilter_register_all();

    if ((ret = open_input_file(argv[1])) < 0)
        goto end;
    if ((ret = open_output_file(argv[2])) < 0)
        goto end;

    /* read all packets */
    while (1) {
        if ((ret = av_read_frame(ifmt_ctx, &packet)) < 0)
            break;
        stream_index = packet.stream_index;
        type = ifmt_ctx->streams[packet.stream_index]->codecpar->codec_type;
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_DEBUG, "Demuxer gave frame of stream_index %u\n",
            stream_index);

         if (type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
         {
             av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_DEBUG, "Going to reencode&filter the frame\n");
             frame = av_frame_alloc();
             if (!frame) {
                 ret = AVERROR(ENOMEM);
                 break;
             }
             av_packet_rescale_ts(&packet,
                 ifmt_ctx->streams[stream_index]->time_base,
                 stream_ctx[stream_index].dec_ctx->time_base);
             dec_func = avcodec_decode_video2;
             ret = dec_func(stream_ctx[stream_index].dec_ctx, frame,
                 &got_frame, &packet);
             if (ret < 0) {
                 av_frame_free(&frame);
                 av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Decoding failed\n");
                 break;
             }

             if (got_frame) {
                 frame->pts = frame->best_effort_timestamp;
                 ret = filter_encode_write_frame(frame, stream_index);
                 av_frame_free(&frame);
                 if (ret < 0)
                     goto end;
             }
             else {
                 av_frame_free(&frame);
             }
         }
         else 
        {
            /* remux this frame without reencoding */
            av_packet_rescale_ts(&packet,
                ifmt_ctx->streams[stream_index]->time_base,
                ofmt_ctx->streams[stream_index]->time_base);

            ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(ofmt_ctx, &packet);
            if (ret < 0)
                goto end;
        }
        av_packet_unref(&packet);
    }

    av_write_trailer(ofmt_ctx);
end:
    av_packet_unref(&packet);
    av_frame_free(&frame);
    for (i = 0; i < ifmt_ctx->nb_streams; i++) {
        avcodec_free_context(&stream_ctx[i].dec_ctx);
        if (ofmt_ctx && ofmt_ctx->nb_streams > i && ofmt_ctx->streams[i] && stream_ctx[i].enc_ctx)
            avcodec_free_context(&stream_ctx[i].enc_ctx);
    }
    av_free(stream_ctx);
    avformat_close_input(&ifmt_ctx);
    if (ofmt_ctx && !(ofmt_ctx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE))
        avio_closep(&ofmt_ctx->pb);
    avformat_free_context(ofmt_ctx);

    return ret ? 1 : 0;
}
```

And the result is different.

For a test I took a SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb.flv.
It has

> File size                      : 1.00 MiB 
>   Overall bit rate             : 1 630 kb/s

After my decode/encode actions the result became:

> File size                      : 1.23 MiB 
>   Overall bit rate            : 2 005 kb/s

Other parameters (video bit rate, audio bit rate, etc) are the same.
[image]

What am I doing wrong? How to control overall bit rate? I suppose, something wrong with encoder/decoder, but what?

**UPD:**
I get that when in function `open_input_file` I write

```
if (codec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
{
     codec_ctx->framerate = av_guess_frame_rate(ifmt_ctx, stream, NULL);
}
```

I get what I get (bigger size and bit rate).

And when in this function I write

```
if (codec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
{
    codec_ctx = ifmt_ctx->streams[i]->codec;
}
```

I get smaller size and bit rate.

> File size                      : 900 KiB 
>   Overall bit rate             : 1 429 kb/s

But how to get the exactly size and frame rate as in the original file?